# GitLab: This job could not start because it could not retrieve the needed artifacts: Build

Tags: maven, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am getting *"This job could not start because it could not retrieve the needed artifacts: Build"* error when trying to run integration test after deployment on `GitLab`.

There is not any details or log regarding to the error. So, how can I get the details or solve the problem? Before deploy I already run all the tests with `mvn clean install`. Any idea?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution to this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because job’s dependencies are not found. Other words, pipeline on early stage is creating artifacts which is going to use on later stage. If something went wrong is unable to reach those artifacts. To solve it, you need to simply earlier stages (where the artefacts where created). If you not sure which one is it, you can ran it from the beginning. [Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts_troubleshooting.html#error-message-this-job-could-not-start-because-it-could-not-retrieve-the-needed-artifacts), in docs is more about it.